# How to pass path as const variable in require.context()?

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I am using require.context() to dynamically get all the svgs name and location present in a folder (`./icon-pack1`)

## CASE 1 - Works Perfectly Fine

```js
  useEffect(() => {
   
   
    const images = importAll(require.context("./icon-pack1", false, /\.svg$/)); //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

    allSVGsRef.current = Object.keys(images).map(imgName => {
      return (
        <>
          <img src={images[imgName]} alt="" />
        </>
      );
    });
  }, []);
```

## CASE 2 - gives error

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    const iconLoc = "./icon-pack1";                                      //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    const images = importAll(require.context(iconLoc, false, /\.svg$/)); //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<


    allSVGsRef.current = Object.keys(images).map(imgName => {
      return (
        <>
          <img src={images[imgName]} alt="" />
        </>
      );
    });
  }, []);
```

**ERROR**
[image]

I want to take advantage of case 2. Instead of `iconLoc`, there I will be using `props.iconLoc` so that I can dynamically import all svgs present in any folder (e.g. ./icon-pack1, ./icon-pack2, etc)

If case2 cant be used like that, then please suggest an alternative

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: no . No solution found yet. you have to import em like shown in Case1